# How to query Jsonb data with PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I am creating some views by working with those data bassically UUID and some concepts, I managed to obtain what I expected from the first level, but I am having problems when trying to obtain second level data.
The table I am working within the column tiledata are some nested data which I would like to access, this is the

[image: table I am working on]

When I run the query

```
SELECT tileid, nodegroupid,
   tiledata ->'34cfea8a-c2c0-11ea-9026-02e7594ce0a0' AS ACTOR
   FROM tiles
   WHERE tiledata -> '34cfea8a-c2c0-11ea-9026-02e7594ce0a0' IS NOT NULL;
```

I obtain this

[image: after query]

How Could I obtain for example resourceId from this nested data,

[image: obtaining all the rows which have resourceId]

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) which can be copied to build up a test-bed. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `jsonb_array_elements` function to extract each element of a JSONB array as a new JSONB value on which you can use any other JSONB function or operator.

The thing to know is that each array value will generate a new row in the record set.

---

In your case, you can try:

```sql
SELECT tileid, nodegroupid,
   jsonb_array_elements(tiledata ->'34cfea8a-c2c0-11ea-9026-02e7594ce0a0')->'resourceID'
   FROM tiles
   WHERE tiledata -> '34cfea8a-c2c0-11ea-9026-02e7594ce0a0' IS NOT NULL;
```

---

See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2a78d4f5b788992dfe46ded9038d0626) for a simple example.

See [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html) for more details.